# twitter error share link

Tags: twitter

These are the steps to experiment twitter error with share link:

1. Logout from twitter.
2. go to `twitter.com/home?status=the status here`
3. output: got login page and login
4. result: post login page ignoring the status

Any workarround to keep the status message post-login?

thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

twitter developers, did you see that question?

they had fixed this bug 1 or 2 days after this question was asked.

when they detect not logged in user the url changes to:

`http://twitter.com/login?redirect_after_login=/home?status=the%20status%20here`

;)